# How to get charset via php imap when imap_fetchmime isnt supported

Tags: php, imap

I'm wondering how to get the charset via PHP IMAP when [imap_fetchmime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchmime.php) isn't supported. I either have a lower version of PHP that doesn't support it or maybe it's deprecated, but it doesn't work for me.

What I basically need is to find out the charset of the email via IMAP, so the output would be:

```
ISO-8859-1
```

Or whatever it turns out to be. I don't want to read the whole email to find out, I want to find out what the charset is so I can use the correct encoding.

Here is the code I'm using simplified down for the purpose of this email:

```
$mailbox = "xxx@gmail.com";
$mailboxPassword = "xxx";

$mailbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX",
mailbox, $mailboxPassword);

mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$subject = mb_decode_mimeheader(str_replace('_', ' ', $subject));

$body = imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $val, 1);
$body = base64_decode($body);

echo $body;
```

Comment: Fetch and parse the MIME headers.

Comment: Thats the problem though, i dont know where to get these mime headers, where are they stored?

Comment: They are part of the message's headers. You want Content-type and Content-transfer-encoding in particular, but you need to understand their correct use and context, too, especially for multipart messages.